# Can I configure windows-7 to enable function keys on my keyboard by default upon reboot?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have a keyboard from Logitech that has a F-Lock key that is required for the function keys to produce F1 through f12 instead of special functions for things like 'new' and 'reply'.

Each time I reboot, the setting defaults to off, is there a way to configure windows-7 perhaps through the registry to have the keyboard default to this setting on upon a reboot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, the later ones have the F-lock functionality reversed by default so it's not so annoying.

If your keyboard is supported by it, may want to install the newest [Logitech SetPoint](http://www.logitech.com/pub/techsupport/mouse/setpoint480.exe) and see if it lets you change it's behaviour.

Also, if you've got it hooked up via PS/2 you might be able to make use of [this registry hack](http://www.ben.pope.name/logitech.html).

HTH.

Comment: Its via USB port.